# How to sort the ActiveAdmin index based on a filter and a column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a Rails application with a Movie model. The Movie model has 'name' and 'release_date' as regular attributes, as well as a scope used to search for movie names with elasticsearch.

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base

   scope :movie_name_search, -> (term) {
     movie_ids = elasticSearch(term, :name).map(&id)
     Movie.where(id: movie_ids).reorder('').order_by_ids(movie_ids) unless movie_ids.nil?     
   }

end
```

I then set up my active admin to show this data

```
ActiveAdmin.register Promotion do
  filter :movie_name_search, as: :string, label: "Movie Name"

  index do
    actions
    column :name
    column :release date, sortable: :release_date
  end

end
```

Putting in a movie name into the search bar works perfectly, and sorting against release_date works perfectly, but I can't do both at the same time. Once I'm using the filter for movie names, the sort by date doesn't work. It only works when I remove the reorder and new order.

```
scope :movie_name_search, -> (term) {
   movie_ids = elasticSearch(term, :name).map(&id)
   Movie.where(id: movie_ids) unless movie_ids.nil?     
}
```

It would appear that the ordering I enforce in the scope takes precedence over the sort of the column but I have no idea why. Any ideas?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the code above, save the space where an underscore should be in `column :release date`. The `sortable` part should be redundant here too.

Comment: You're right, after some debugging I narrowed down the problem and updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

You're resetting the scope chain when you call `Movie.where` in `movie_search_name`. You want to send `where` to `self` instead (i.e. just delete the `Movie.` part), so that prior conditions are preserved.

```
scope :movie_name_search, -> (term) {
  movie_ids = elasticSearch(term, :name).map(&id)
  where(id: movie_ids) unless movie_ids.nil?     
}
```

**Edit: I understand the issue now**

Like you say, Elastic Search is returning an array of `id`s in sorted order, but `where` does not respect that order. It just pulls records from the database as it finds them, so long as their `id`s are in the array. It's no good for us to sort the records afterwards as an array, because then ActiveRecord can't apply additional clauses to the query. It has to be done as part of the query.

SQL does provide a way to enforce an arbitrary order: `ORDER BY CASE`, but it's not built in to Rails. Fortunately, it's not hard to add.

Let's suppose your search results are `[2, 1, 3]`. In SQL, we can retrieve them in order like this:

```
SELECT * FROM movies
  WHERE id IN (2, 1, 3)
  ORDER BY CASE id
    WHEN 2 THEN 0
    WHEN 1 THEN 1
    WHEN 3 THEN 2
    ELSE 3 END;
```

To make this compatible with ActiveRecord, we can add a class method to Movie:

**app/models/movie.rb**

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base

  # ...

  def self.order_by_ids_array(ids)
    order_clause = "CASE id "
    ids.each_with_index do |id, index|
      order_clause << sanitize_sql_array(["WHEN ? THEN ? ", id, index])
    end
    order_clause << sanitize_sql_array(["ELSE ? END", ids.length])
    order(order_clause)
  end
end
```

Now your ActiveAdmin scope uses both `where` and `order_by_ids_array`:

```
scope :movie_name_search, -> (term) {
  movie_ids = elasticSearch(term, :name).map(&id)
  where(id: movie_ids).order_by_ids_array(movie_ids) unless movie_ids.nil?     
}
```

Reference:

http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-to-select-database-records-in-an-arbitrary-order/

**Edit II: A real hack**

Note: This requires a recent version of ActiveAdmin that uses Ransack.

The issue we're having is that filters don't play well with sorting. So here's
the new plan: let's add another column to our index table that shows the search
rank of each movie. This column will only appear when we've filtered by movie
name, and it will be sortable. This way there will be no "default" sort, but
you can sort by anything you want, including search ranking.

The trick is to insert a computed column into the query using a `CASE` like
above, but in the `SELECT` clause. We'll call it `search_rank` and it can be
accessed on any returned movie as `movie.attributes['search_rank']`.

**app/admin/movies.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Movie do

  filter :movie_search, as: string, label: 'Movie Name'

  index do

    # only show this column when a search term is present
    if params[:q] && params[:q][:movie_search]

      # we'll alias this column to `search_rank` in our scope so it can be sorted by
      column :search_rank, sortable: 'search_rank' do |movie|
        movie.attributes['search_rank']
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Now in our model, we need to define the `movie_search` scope (as a class method)
and mark it as ransackable.

**app/models/movie.rb**

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.ransackable_scopes(opts)
    [:movie_search]
  end

  def self.movie_search(term)
    # do search here
    ids = elasticSearch(term, :name).map(&id)

    # build extra column
    rank_col = "(CASE movies.id "
    ids.each_with_index do |id, index|
      rank_col << "WHEN #{ id } THEN #{ index } "
    end
    rank_col << 'ELSE NULL END) AS search_rank'

    select("movies.*, #{ rank_col }").where(id: ids)
  end
end
```

Comment: This allows me to sort by date when I'm filtered by movie title, however it doesn't keep the original order of the filter when the sort is not applied. For example, my original filter would give me A1, A2, A3, A4 and now it gives me A3, A1, A2, A4 when no sort is applied. I would like to retain the original sort order.

Comment: My guess is that elastic search is returning the `id`s in an arbitary order. You could try adding a `.sort` after `map(&:id)`.

Comment: Really? I assumed that ElasticSearch would return them in the order with the best match first. In the example in my comment, A1 is not the smallest ID but the best ID.

Comment: I misunderstood. Try the full solution above.

Comment: I just realized: this is probably going to interfere with your ability to sort, since the `ORDER BY CASE` clause will likely take precedence over the selected column sort.

Comment: It doesn't work as is so I'm trying to fix it, but yes I also expect it to suffer from the same problems.

Comment: I took one more stab at it, try the last solution above.

Comment: It doesn't play nicely, when I try to sort by search rank it breaks saying that that column is undefined. Even so, this solution is too hackish for my purposes, for now I'm going to accept the limitations of ActiveAdmin. Thanks for trying!

Comment: It worked when I tested it. If you're using `includes` anywhere, it might be overriding the custom `select`.